# sending http request from angular js to node server

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using angular.js as my client side js and Node.js as a server. I am getting result with $http requests successfully. but, When I change network from LAN to Wi-fi or vice versa, not able to send any requests from client to node server.

Any help in this regard will be very helpful

Comment: We need more info on the server you're running, Is it on localhost or 127.0.0.1? if yes, you will need to configure port, etc... Running it from 127.0.0.1 or localhost is different than acceding it using your local IP ex 192.168. x. x. On LAN or WI-fi.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @Shahzad Service in angular.js is not able to make any call to node server. after sometime I get an error GET http://casaclue.local/home/dashboardreports?page=1 net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Comment: @m.nachury lan and wi-fi have same ip

Comment: After switching back to lan or wi-fi with which I have authenticated user for the first time, I am able to get all the response from API

Comment: Yes but when you connect to the server do you use 127.0.0.1/locahost. Or your Lan/Wifi address?

Comment: I used for iisnode. The website is hosted on IIS as well

Comment: 127.0.0.1 I use in host file